# Using JavaScript to validate select field on form statement is not working

Tags: javascript, forms, validation

I am trying to use JavaScript to validate all fields on this form but am stuck on the select field and textbox validation.  The text field, radio and checkbox validations are working but I can't seem to figure out the selection and textbox and there are no errors when i run the script.... also, I need to do this without changing the HTML(no ID tags)    What am i doing wrong? Thanks as always!

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Validate me</title>
<script>

    console.log(document.forms);

    function validateForm(){
        var show = document.getElementsByName('show').value
        var comments = document.getElementsByName('comments');
        for (var i=0;i < document.forms[0].length - 1; i++){
            if (document.forms[0][i].type == 'text' && document.forms[0][i].value==''){
                alert('Please Enter Your Full Name');
                return false;
            }
            else if (document.forms[0][i].type == 'radio'){
                if (document.forms[0].gender[0].checked == false && document.forms[0].gender[1].checked == false){
                    alert('Please select gender');
                    return false;
                }
            }
            else if (document.forms[0][i].type == 'checkbox'){
                var hobbies = document.getElementsByName('hobbies[]');
                if (hobbies[0].checked == false && hobbies[1].checked == false && hobbies[2].checked == false){
                    alert('Please select hobby');
                    return false;
                }
            }

            else if (show == 'Choose Below'){
                alert('Please Select a Favorite Show');
                return false;
            }


            else if(comments.value == 'Enter Comments'|| comments.value == ''){
                alert('Please provide comments');
                return false;
            }


            console.log(document.forms[0][i].type);
        }


    }

    </script>
</head>
<body>
At lease one piece of data has to come in from every input type.
<form action = "form.html" method = "get"><br/>
Name:<input type = "text" name = "fullname" placeholder="Enter Full Name"/><br/>
Gender:<br/>
Male<input type = "radio" name = "gender" value="male"/>Female<input type = "radio" name = "gender" value="female"/><br/>
Hobbies<br/>
Baseball <input type = "checkbox" name = "hobbies[]" value = "baseball" />  
Football <input type = "checkbox" name = "hobbies[]" value = "football" />  
Hockey <input type = "checkbox" name = "hobbies[]" value = "hockey" /><br/>
Favorite Show <select name = "show">
<option value = "">Choose Below</option>
<option value = "ATHF">Aqua Teen Hunger Force</option>
<option value = "Family Guy">Family Guy</option>
<option value = "Simpsons">Simpsons</option>
</select><br/>
Comments<br/>
<textarea cols = "50" rows = "6" name = "comments">Enter Comments</textarea><br/>
<input type = "button" name = "submit" value = "enter me" onclick="return validateForm();" />
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: As the name implies, `document.getElementsByName()` returns a list of elements ([`NodeList`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NodeList)). Use `document.getElementsByName(...)[0]` to grab the first one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**strong text** This is the more easy form to validate this

```js
<script>

    console.log(document.forms);

    function validateForm(){
        var showData = document.getElementsByName("show");
  var show = showData[0][showData[0].selectedIndex].text;
        var comments = document.getElementsByName('comments');
        for (var i=0;i < document.forms[0].length - 1; i++){
            if (document.forms[0][i].type == 'text' && document.forms[0][i].value==''){
                alert('Please Enter Your Full Name');
                return false;
            }
            else if (document.forms[0][i].type == 'radio'){
                if (document.forms[0].gender[0].checked == false && document.forms[0].gender[1].checked == false){
                    alert('Please select gender');
                    return false;
                }
            }
            else if (document.forms[0][i].type == 'checkbox'){
                var hobbies = document.getElementsByName('hobbies[]');
                if (hobbies[0].checked == false && hobbies[1].checked == false && hobbies[2].checked == false){
                    alert('Please select hobby');
                    return false;
                }
            }

            else if (show == 'Choose Below'){
                alert('Please Select a Favorite Show');
                return false;
            }


            else if(comments[0].textContent == 'Enter Comments'|| comments.value == ''){
                alert('Please provide comments');
                return false;
            }


            console.log(document.forms[0][i].type);
        }


    }

    </script>
```